# How to apply Discrete Fourier Transform's shift theorem in Python?

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to better understand the Discrete Fourier Transform and its shift theorem.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
from numpy.fft import fft
from numpy.fft import ifft
from numpy.fft import fftshift
from numpy.fft import ifftshift

FFT = lambda x: fftshift(fft(ifftshift(x)))
IFFT = lambda x: fftshift(ifft(ifftshift(x)))
```

First I make array `x`:

```
x = np.arange(1, 11)
x

    array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Apply circular shift of size `1` to `x`:

```
y = np.append(x[1:], x[0])
y

    array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  1])
```

Apply FFT to `x`:

```
xfft = FFT(x)
xfft

    array([ 5.+1.33226763e-15j, -5.-1.62459848e+00j,  5.+3.63271264e+00j,
           -5.-6.88190960e+00j,  5.+1.53884177e+01j, 55.+0.00000000e+00j,
            5.-1.53884177e+01j, -5.+6.88190960e+00j,  5.-3.63271264e+00j,
           -5.+1.62459848e+00j])
```

Compute the FFT of shifted `x`:

```
shift = np.exp(-1j*2*pi*(1/10)*x)
xfft * shift

    array([ 4.04508497e+00-2.93892626e+00j, -3.09016994e+00+4.25325404e+00j,
            1.90983006e+00-5.87785252e+00j, -8.88178420e-16+8.50650808e+00j,
           -5.00000000e+00-1.53884177e+01j, -4.44959347e+01+3.23281889e+01j,
            1.30901699e+01+9.51056516e+00j, -8.09016994e+00-2.62865556e+00j,
            6.18033989e+00+3.55271368e-15j, -5.00000000e+00+1.62459848e+00j])
```

Problem: The above doesn't equal the FFT of `y`:

```
FFT(y)

    array([-5.        +4.44089210e-16j,  3.09016994+4.25325404e+00j,
            1.90983006-5.87785252e+00j, -8.09016994+2.62865556e+00j,
           13.09016994+9.51056516e+00j, 55.        +0.00000000e+00j,
           13.09016994-9.51056516e+00j, -8.09016994-2.62865556e+00j,
            1.90983006+5.87785252e+00j,  3.09016994-4.25325404e+00j])
```